# Write a query to print a letter when a number is given

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to write a query to print the letter when i give number as input
1-a
2-b
3-c
4-d
5-f
and so on
using either SQL or PL/SQL query.

one way of doing it is:

> `begin
>   case when 1 then 'a'
>   when 2 then 'b'
>   when 3 then 'c'
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   when 26 then 'z'
>   .
>   .
>   end;`

But is there any other way of writing it instead of such a long query.

Comment: what do you need? what have you tried so far? Please give sample data

Comment: what happens when you want to replace 11 how do you know it's not aa instead of k? or do you really mean the whole set consts of 1-4 only and a-d?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Oracle (as per the [plsql](/questions/tagged/plsql) tag and the mention of the `DECODE` construct), you're looking for the `TRANSLATE` function.
It accepts a string to translate a pair of `from` and `to` strings, and then replaces every character from the string to translate that appears in the `from` with the corresponding character in the `to` string:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE (<your input here>, '1234', 'abcd') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

tricky to see what you mean as you have not included any SQL or specified which flavour of database you are using.
also, what about the higher numbers. for example if Z is 26, then how do you tell if its B+F or Z.
assuming you are limiting from a to I or are going to comma delimit the numbers, then you could use a replace function along 
the lines of REPLACE(str,num,CHR(64+num))

in this example assuming the str is "1"
then it would be replaced with the character with the ascii code 64+1=65 which is a

note that syntax, functions vary between databases, but most have a string replace and ascii code to char function. you might also
need to cast the value to a number on some db's